# PHP Regex to remove specific CSS Comment

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to write the regular expression in php matching condition below:

```
   /* 
    Remove this comment line 1
    Remove this comment line 2
   */
   .class1
   {
      background:#CCC url(images/bg.png);
   }

   .class2
   {
      color: #FFF;
      background:#666 url(images/bg.png); /* DON'T remove this comment */
   }

   /* Remove this comment */
   .class3
   {
      margin:2px;
      color:#999;
      background:#FFF; /* DON'T Remove this comment */
   }

    ...etc
    ...etc
```

Please any one give me a regular expression in php. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you remove all comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rule is that you want to remove all comments where there is no other code on the line then something like this should work:

```
/^(\s*\/\*.*?\*\/\s*)$/m
```

The 'm' option makes ^ and $ match the beginning and end of a line. Do you expect the comments to run for more than one line?

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure this fits the bill:

```
/(^|\n)\s*\/\*.*?\*\/\s*/s
```

Do you understand what it's doing?

Comment: actually: /(^|\n)\s*\/\*.*?\*\/\s*(\n|$)/s

Comment: `/\n\s*\/*.*?*\/\s*\n/s` and `/(^|\n)\s*\/*.*?*\/\s*(\n|$)/s` not working for me , @Godwin. Produce some error when using preg_replace.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think there was something off when I cut and pasted. Check the edit in the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not working for multiline comments like

```
/*
 * Lorem ipsum
 */
```

This one do the job

```
$regex = "!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!";
$newstr = preg_replace($regex,"",$str);
echo $newstr;
```

http://codepad.org/xRb2Gdhy

Found here : http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/3-ways-to-compress-css-files-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Codepad: http://codepad.org/aMvQuJSZ

Support multiline:

```
/* Remove this comment 
multi-lane style 1*/

/* Remove this comment 
multi-lane style 2
*/

/* Remove this comment */
```

Regex Explanation:

```
^            Start of line
\s*          only contains whitespace
\/\*         continue with /*
[^(\*\/)]*   unlimited number of character except */ includes newline
\*\/         continue with */
m            pattern modifier (makes ^ start of line, $ end of line
```

Example php code:

```
$regex = "/^\s*\/\*[^(\*\/)]*\*\//m";
$newstr = preg_replace($regex,"",$str);
echo $newstr;
```

Comment: Thanks, its work in one line comment, how about multi line comment. like: `/****** Line1 line2 line3 ******/`